# Fastest way to see what unique dates are in a table's timestamp field?

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I have a table with billions of rows. There are daily partitions on the "recorded" field, which is a "timestamp without time zone." I want to know which days are currently in the table. I know I could do something like:

```
SELECT recorded::date
FROM table
GROUP BY 1;
```

Which ideally should work, but the explain on that is rather high, and indicates it would take quite a while to work... if that's the best I can do, I can accept that (and we could keep tabs on the data as it goes in), but I was wondering if there might be a more efficient way to do this, given that I have daily partitioning?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an index something like this:

```
create index your_index_name
on table (date_trunc('day', recorded))
```

In my test, PostgreSQL 9.something used a sequential scan before adding the index, a sequential scan after simply indexing the column "recorded", and an index scan after indexing it with date_trunc(). Selecting a single day's rows took 66ms without an index, 68ms with a plain index, and 13ms with an index using date_trunc().

With billions of rows, expect creating that index to take a few minutes. (cough)

Answer (score 1):

There's a very similar thread here:

[Slow select distinct query on postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032796/slow-select-distinct-query-on-postgres/6033977#6033977)

If you know the min/max dates, you'll be better off querying against a list of dates than doing a seq scan over the whole table. Assuming you've an index on recorded, something that looks like this should be faster:

```
with days as (
select date_trunc('day', min(recorded))::date + k * interval '1 day' as day
from records,
     generate_series(0,
                    (select date_trunc('day', max(recorded))::date
                            - date_trunc('day', min(recorded)::date
                    from records
     )) as k
)
select day
from days
where exists (
      select 1
      from records
      where day <= recorded and recorded < day + interval '1 day'
      );
```

There might be a few tweaks to do to the above query, but the general idea is there: it'll be faster to do a few thousand subquery/index scans on an indexed field than it is to seq scan a few billions of rows and aggregate them in order to identify the distinct days.

Comment: If the table is partitioned with one partition per day, you don't even need an index on the date since constraint exclusion will pick the right table, and the first row read from the table will satisfy the EXISTS.