# Query for distinct values in postgres and php

Tags: php, postgresql

I have the following code:

```
$sql_sd = select sd_code from stamp_den;
$rest2   = odbc_exec($conn,$sql_sd);
while(odbc_fetch_into($rest2,$row_s))
 {             
   $row_sd=$row_s[0];
 }
  //here i get sd_code as follows: 45, 46, 47, 48 etc
for ($i=0; $i<$td_date ;$i++)
 {
   $qu=select stamp_type from stamp_type where sd_code=$row_sd; 
 }
```

This whole code is inside another while loop.

Now in the for loop while executing the '$qu' query it takes values of sd_code as 45,45,45,45,46,46,46,46 etc depending upon the number of iterations.

How can I modify the code to take distinct values of sd_code while executing the $qu query. (45,46,47, etc)

If there is problem with the syntax please ignore, all variables and loops are declared. My code is executing properly, but not giving the desired o/p.

Comment: you can just you SQL like this => `SELECT DISTINCT sd_code from stamp_den` to receive distinct values from database

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032796/slow-select-distinct-query-on-postgres

Comment: @DaHaKa what you suggested is the real solution, why not post it as an answer and get some credit for your suggestion

Comment: Why aren't you just running SELECT sd_code, stamp_type FROM stamp_den JOIN stamp_code USING (sd_code) ORDER BY sd_code, stamp_type and then building a map of sd_codes to lists of stamp_types and work with that? They way you appear to be doing things now will probably generate in an order of magnitude or more of network traffic via database trips.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sd_code from stamp_den
```

`DISTINCT` is used to receive unique data from database.